# In Swagger, how to use one field as the discriminator to control another field polymophism

Tags: swagger

I try to create a swagger for the following case: if the `switchName` is `switch1`, then use the "1" schema for `case`; if the `switchName` is `switch2`, then use the "2" schema for `case`.

```
"properties": {
...
  "switchName": "switch1 | switch2",
  "case": {
    ... 1 ...
  },
  "case": {
    ... 2 ...
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to use swagger to describe it and I did not find sample for this case on the Internet. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Your problem is not with Swagger as much as it is a problem with JSON schema definitions.  It is bad practice to bleed polymorphism into your data contracts (i.e. requests and responses).  This is something I say out of both experience and pragmatism.  If you want to make an API easy to use then you need to be able to very easily articulate the resource that you are representing.  Bleeding polymorphic objects into your API contract makes it crazy complicated and problematic in many indirect ways. GET /cars/{id} should always return a car, not a dog or a country.

Comment: Sort of agree on this API design philosophy. But sometimes, it is an existing API and I have to deal with it. But the good thing is I have found the way to solve it. I will answer my question once I verified the solution completely.

Comment: @NonStatic did your solution work? If so, would love to see an answer with a toy example!

Comment: @JohnBaum, There is no generic solution for this. For Microsoft AutoRest, there is a solution: https://github.com/Azure/autorest/tree/master/docs/extensions#x-ms-discriminator-value